# PHP- Adding ":" character to all words in string

Tags: php

I want to add ":" character to all words in string like;

`$user = "name, surname, username"`

`$newString = ":name, :surname, :username"`

How can I do that ?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I'm thinking, but I can' find a logical solution.. Sorry I know questions has must example codes , but I don't have even it..

Comment: I have answered man... Check the answer and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$user = "name, surname, username";
$words = explode(', ', $user);
$newString = implode(', ', array_map(function($i) {return ':' . $i;}, $words));
```

Assuming `', '` is your delimiter. If not, replace it.

Comment: I like this one more clean :)

Answer (score 1):

Yep

```
$string = preg_replace('/\b(\w)/', ':$1', $string);
```

Outputs

```
:name, :surname, :username
```

Try it [online](https://regex101.com/r/VrJJhQ/1)

To explain

- `\b` -  matches a word bondry
- `(\w)` - captures a single `a-zA-Z0-9_`

Then

- `:` just adds that in
- `$1` adds the captured char in.

Simple, The word boundary means that we capture the first character, then we add the `:` and that capture back in.

Comment: Thank you for reply,  I need to start learn about regex.. Do you have any suggest for doc or video tutorial ?

Comment: Not really but this site that the tester is on https://regex101.com/r/VrJJhQ/1/ has a lot of help stuff on the lower right.

Comment: @HasanTıngır you might want to read this documentation, it is quite a steep learning curve but the end results will be worth the effort for sure: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
<?php
    $user = "name, surname, username";
    $array = explode(", ", $user);
    $array = array();
    foreach ($array as $use) {
        $array[] = ":" . $use;
    }
    $array = implode(", ", $array);
    var_dump($array);
?>
```

The output I get is:

```
string(26) ":name, :surname, :username"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple technique using [preg_replace](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_preg_replace.htm) which is for regular expressions.

```
$user = "name, surname, username";
$user = ":" . $user; //appends to beginning of string
$new_string = preg_replace('/, /',',:', $user ); //the pattern can be written better searching for ', '
```

Comment: missing the delimiters in your Regx