# Add characters in front of all words Regex/Typescript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently trying to add simple Math solving capability's to my discord bot, which is done by first sterilizing user input (to fix security issues), then running it via `new Function`. The issue is that I would like all the functions currently inside the `Math` object to be stand alone for the user, heres what I mean:

To get the square root of a number, inside of JS I could use `Math.sqrt(25)`. I don't want the user to have to deal with the `Math.`, so ideally they would just use `sqrt(25)`. The total message might look something like: `!solve sqrt(25)`, which would return 5.

Because the message content is already a string, and has been sterilized, the only things in this string would be: numbers, operations (+, -, *, /, ^ or **), or mathematical functions (cos, sin, sqrt, etc.). Because these mathematical functions are the only "words" in here, a really simple way around this issue is to just take all the "words" in this string, add `Math.` before each one, and then solve the equation.

Here is the psudo code and example:

```
Psudocode:                              | Example:
 1. Get user input                      |  input = '! solve 5 + cos(10) / sqrt(50)*random()'
 2. Trim input to only the equation     |  input = '5 + cos(10) / sqrt(50)*random()'
 3. Add Math. to beginning of words     |  input = '5 + Math.cos(10) / Math.sqrt(50)*Math.random()'
 4. Compile into result variable        |  result = new Function(`return ${input}`);
 5. If step 4 failed, tell user         |  send(`bla is not a math function`); //<-- if input was bla(50)
 6. Send user result                    |  send(result);
```

I have every step except step 4 worked out, and this is where I need some understanding. I found this [PHP- Adding ":" character to all words in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713019/php-adding-character-to-all-words-in-string) PHP function, which my brain cant seem to understand, and this [Regular Expression - Add a character before/after each word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614144/regular-expression-add-a-character-before-after-each-word) notepad answer, which would have worked, except the replacer was a regex itself, which Js' `string.replace()` does not accept, confirmed by typescript. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Once the String is sanitized, there is no need to replace anything, if you extract the methods or properties you want to allow from `Math`:

```js
const input = '5 + cos(10) / sqrt(50)*random()';
const { sqrt, pow, random, cos, sin, PI } = Math;
console.log(eval(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @blex is good. Here is another solution doing a global search and replace on alpha characters:

```js
function evalExpr(str) {
  try {
    str = str.replace(/\b([a-z]+ *\()/g, 'Math.$1');
    return eval(str);
  } catch(e) {
    return 'Error evaluating "' + str + '"';
  }
}

const input = 'round((5 + cos(10) / sqrt(50)) * 10) / 10';
console.log(input + ' = ' + evalExpr(input));
```

The regex has a word boundary, followed by 1+ alpha chars, followed by optional spaces, followed by an opening parenthesis